# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1-centos

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to install Mysql-python connector for mysql.I am facing this error"`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`"

I tried with installation of 
1.gcc using `yum install gcc`
2.python-devel and mysql-devel using `yum install python-devel mysql-devel`

Nothing solved my problem.

Please see my traceback:

```
[root@localhost MySQL-python-1.2.4b4]# python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) -D__version__=1.2.4b4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
_mysql.c:602: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Need help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a broken package.

Comment: This appears to be a compilation error.  Report it to Mysql-python connector maintainers.

Comment: Appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues/6). Download a version that's not 1.2.4.

Comment: @svk If i use MySQL-python-1.2.3 or MySQL-python-1.2.2 ,this issue wont appear and i can install it successfully right.